# Filtering a Collection in a ListView in WPF

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, listview, mvvm

I'm creating an WPF application that allows a user to enter some details about their Employee, using `Entity Framework`, CRUD operations and MVVM.

So far, I have two `ListViews`. One contains a list of employees names (listview1), while the other (listview2) lists their details such as Date of Birth, address etc. The Image below will give you a better picture of what I'm creating;

[image: ListView]

I am using a `CollectionViewSoruce` to enable me to filter the results on listview2 when you select a specific name from listbox1. So far I am able to achieve this, but When I add an employee or delete, it throws an exception;

```
 An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in *.UI.exe
```

Here are the code snippets that might help

ViewModel:

```
    private EmployeeListViewModel()
        : base("")
    {
        EmployeeList = new ObservableCollection<EmployeeViewModel>(GetEmployees());
        this._employeeCol = new ListCollectionView(this.employeeList); 
    }

    private ListCollectionView _employeeCol;
    public ICollectionView EmployeeCollection
    {
        get { return this._employeeCol; }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<EmployeeViewModel> employeeList;
    public ObservableCollection<EmployeeViewModel> EmployeeList
    {
        get { return employeeList; }
        set
        {
            employeeList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("EmployeeList");
        }
    }

    private EmployeeViewModel selectedEmployee = null;
    public EmployeeViewModel SelectedEmployee
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedEmployee;
        }
        set
        {
            selectedEmployee = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedEmployee");
            EmployeeCollection.Filter = new Predicate<object>(o => SelectedEmployee != null && o != null && ((EmployeeViewModel)o).EmployeeID == SelectedEmployee.EmployeeID);
        }
    }

    internal ObservableCollection<EmployeeViewModel> GetEmployees()
    {
        if (employeeList == null)
            employeeList = new ObservableCollection<EmployeeViewModel>();
        employeeList.Clear();

        foreach (DataObjects.Employee i in new EmployeeRepository().GetAllEmployees())
        {
            EmployeeViewModel c = new EmployeeViewModel(i);
            employeeList.Add(c);
        }
        return employeeList;
    }
```

ListView2 - EmployeeListView;

```
            <ListView Name="lsvEmpoyeeList" Height="170" Width="700"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeCollection}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee}">
                    <ListView.View>
                      <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Position" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Position}" Width="100" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="DateOfBirth" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DateOfBirth, StringFormat={}\{0:dd/MM/yyyy\}}" Width="100" />
                     </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

ListView1 - EmployeeSetUpView;

```
            <ListView Height="380" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="lsNames" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="170" 
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee}" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeList}" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Row="1">

        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="FirstName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}" Width="80" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Surname" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Surname}" Width="80" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
   <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource EmployeeListView}" />
```

As you can see, I have put the filter within the `setaccessor`. I placed it within the constructor but what seems to happen is that none of the details appeared on the ListView2.

Furthermore, if I select a row from listview2 rather then from listview1, it also produces the `StackOverFlowException` which I am unsure why.

Any help would be appreciated or advice. Also, sorry for the large question!

Comment: Now what is your real problem, that you get a StackOverflowException or that not details are listed in the ListView2?

Comment: It seems to be a combination of both, and In particular, to do with a filter from my understanding (and quite possibly to do with the binding). Like in the question i stated that if i place the filter within the constructor, it doesn't query the results and no data appears. while if i add the filter within the `setaccessor` it produces the exception. Which is why I am asking this question to know how to improve my application.

Comment: how is the getter of `SelectedEmployee` implemented? Do you have a typo there?

Comment: Exactly how it is in my code snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the UI knows that `EmployeeCollection` has changed

Try adding a `PropertyChanged` event for `EmployeeCollection` in the `SelectedEmployee` setter after the filter is applied.

```
public EmployeeViewModel SelectedEmployee
{
    get { return selectedEmployee;}
    set
    {
        selectedEmployee = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedEmployee");
        EmployeeCollection.Filter = new Predicate<object>(o => SelectedEmployee != null && o != null && ((EmployeeViewModel)o).EmployeeID == SelectedEmployee.EmployeeID);

        // EmployeeCollection view has changed, Notify UI
        OnPropertyChanged("EmployeeCollection");
    }
}
```

And as for the `StackOverflowException` I think this is caused by the fact both `ListView` have a `TwoWay` binding on `SelectedEmployee`, so when one ListView1 changes SelectedItem it causes ListView2 to update its selected item which updates ListView1 and so on, and so on.

Try setting the binding to OneWay for `SelectedEmployee` on ListView2

> SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee, Mode=OneWay}">